# Read contents of large files without using "cat" command in linux

Tags: linux, file, cat

I'm trying a more efficient way of reading file contents in Linux without using the "cat" command, especially for larger file contents, as in such cases `cat` just shoots up the memory and CPU on the server.

One thing that comes to my mind is using a `grep -v "character-set-which-is-unlikely-in-the-file" filename`

But using different character sets every time and hoping it would not appear in the file, wouldn't be efficient.

Any other thoughts ?

Comment: have you tried the `less` command?

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that you are trying to do? Do you just want to access the file on disk, for example so that it gets cached, or do you want to do something with the contents?

Comment: I just want to access the file on disk (reading contents of a file), so it gets cached, but the contents would be large. I've seen cases (unrelated to this) where if I cat the file, especially when I try to pipe it to some other command, the system slows down and the command crashes. So I was wondering if there is a much efficient and faster way than `cat` to access large files

Comment: @Matzy I want to read the full content of the file at once, not page wise

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to read through the file, so it gets cached, the simplest way is perhaps this:

```
cat filename > /dev/null
```

Note that you don't need to show the data on screen to read it from disk. That command reads the file, and ignores the content by dumping it in /dev/null, but it still reads all the data.

If the CPU load goes up, that is probably a *good* thing, meaning that the computer is working hard, and will be finished sooner rather than later. If it *crashes*, though, there is something else wrong.

If you have some specific reason not to use the "cat" command, you can try "dd" instead, but it is more complicated to write and will not be faster:

```
dd if=filename of=/dev/null bs=1M
```

Addendum:

This inspired me to run some tests. On my particular computer both "cat" and "dd" took 24.27-24.31 seconds to read a large file on a mechanical disk when it wasn't already cached, and 0.39-0.40 seconds when it was cached. (Three tests of each case, with very little variability.)

Both these programs contain code to write the data, even if it is dumped to /dev/null, so one could expect that a program specifically written to just read would be slightly faster, but I got the same times when I tried that.